# What is a good aproximation in asymptotic normality?

Tags: statistics

I have a conceptual doubt. For example, suppose I have $X_i \stackrel{iid}{\sim} N(\theta^*,1)$ and I know that (I have the information) $\theta^{*}\geq 0$. So I have the Constrained Maximum Likelihood Estimation:

$$\hat{\theta}_{CMLE} = \max \{\bar{X}_n ,0 \}$$

I know, that if $\theta > 0$, then

$$\sqrt{n}(\hat{\theta}_{CMLE} - \theta^{*}) \to^{d} N(0,1)$$

I have heard that if $\theta^{*}$ is very close to zero, then I will not have a good approximation. For example, if $\theta^{*}= 0.00000000000000001$. Why should not I have a good approximation? If I know that although this $\theta^{*}$ is very small it will always be positive and my convergence above will be valid.  In what sense would this not be a case of good approximation?

Comment: Cross-posted: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/397864/what-is-a-good-aproximation-in-asymptotic-normality.